# Python folder copying issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I'm trying to copy a directory from a portable drive to the main disk using the following lines:

```
temp_command = "xcopy " + new_dir + " " + basedir + "/Libraries/Installed" #This isn't working. Raises error.
    if subprocess.check_output(temp_command) == True: # copy file to local directory on C:
```

And I get this error:

```
Invalid number of parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Jason Core/Boot.py", line 103, in <module>
    control()
  File "E:/Jason Core/Boot.py", line 96, in control
    install_libs()
  File "E:/Jason Core/Boot.py", line 45, in install_libs
    if subprocess.check_output(temp_command) == True: # copy file to local directory on C:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'xcopy c:/Downloads/Python_Libraries E:/Libraries/Installed' returned non-zero exit status 4
```

Any suggestions on what I can change here?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(temp_command) == True` that doesn't work that way: `check_output` returns the output _only if the program completed with a 0 return code_.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the Python shutil library for this?

Comment: The error is from xcopy and not python, return code of 4 is "Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line"

Comment: @TheoretiCAL "invalid syntax on the command line" because of the paths with slashes

Comment: @Mike I didn't know about shutil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `check_output` in a wrong way.

`check_output` returns the output of the command, not `True` or `False`, but only if the command succeeded, which isn't the case here.

Now why isn't it succeeding?

Reasons are multiple, but the most obvious one is that

```
xcopy c:/Downloads/Python_Libraries E:/Libraries/Installed
```

won't work even if the input exists & output can be written, because you're passing names with slashes to `xcopy`, which is an old MS-DOS like command which interprets that as switches.

The proper command would have been:

```
subprocess.check_output([r"xcopy",r"c:\Download\Python_Libraries",r"E:\Libraries\Installed"])
```

(note the *raw* prefix to avoid backslashes being interpreted by python and passing a list of parameters so if there are spaces in paths, quoting is handled automatically)

That way of running `subprocess.check_output` is the right one in the general case, but in this simple case you'd be better off with

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(r"c:\Download\Python_Libraries",r"E:\Libraries\Installed")
```

(no need to run a command to copy files/dirs, python comes with batteries included, as they say: if you get an error there it will be easier to understand it)

Comment: What if I still want to use the temp variables? On this machine, the drive I want to copy from is labeled "E:", but if I put it in another machine it becomes "D:" or "F": depending on how many drives I have. Additionally, that command didn't work, I'm getting that windows can't find c:\download

Comment: I don't see the relation with the python script. If you don't know the path, just tests the paths using `os.path.isdir()`. And to get temp variable: `os.getenv("TEMP")`. Maybe in another question?

Comment: I figured it out - c:\download was where I wanted to copy to, and it must be second in `shutil.copytree()`

Comment: @TobyTobyo, in that case you had it backwards for xcopy.exe as well. Did you check `xcopy /?` at the command line?

Comment: yeah `xcopy` isn't `memcpy`. That's source then destination. That doesn't change the validity of my answer, though.

Comment: @eryksun It works now. I didn't check it in the command line but it works in my code now. I can paste my changes above if you'd like.

Comment: @TobyTobyo, it's good that you figured it out. I just wanted you to read the help text from `xcopy /?` to see how it tells you to use `XCOPY source [destination]`. Start with the docs and always experiment with simple test cases to verify your understanding.